# How to add props to the component using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a Parent Component and i pass RouteComponentprops like below,

```
function Parent({ history }: RouteComponentProps) {
    //some logic
}
```

Now i want to add a prop OpenByDefault to the Parent component like below,

```
interface Props {
    OpenByDefault?: boolean;
}

function Parent({OpenByDefault = false}: Props) {
    //some logic
}
```

i am not sure how to add {history: RouteComponentProps} to this Props as well.I am new to using typescript. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Extend `RouteComponentProps` when defining `Props`
2. Use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)

---

Here's an example of #1:

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
    OpenByDefault?: boolean;
}
```

Then use `Props` instead of `RouteComponentProps` on `Parent`:

```
function Parent({ history, OpenByDefault }: Props) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Here's an example of #2:

```
function Parent({ history, OpenByDefault }: RouteComponentProps & Props) {
    // ...
}
```

`RouteComponentProps & Props` means that the parameter `Parent` accepts is a combination of both `RouteComponentProps` and `Props`.

---

Since you say you're new to this stuff: By convention, `OpenByDefault` should be called `openByDefault` (lower case initial letter). In JavaScript and TypeScript, an initial capital letter is almost only ever used for constructor function names. (In React it's also used for component functions, even when they aren't constructors.)